# Clarifying a step in Christensen's "Frames and Bases: An Introductory Course"

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm reading through Christensen's *Frames and Bases: An Introductory Course*, and can't figure out a step in the proof of Lemma 5.5.3. The claim is that if a sequence $(f_k)$ in a Hilbert space $H$ has a biorthogonal sequence $(g_k)$, i.e. if there exists a sequence $(g_k)$ in $H$ such that $\left< f_j, g_k \right> = \delta(j, k)$, then $(f_k)$ is *minimal*, i.e. $f_j \not \in \overline {\operatorname{span}} \{ f_k : k \neq j \}$ for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$. My problem is that the author doesn't justify this at all, and I can't figure out why this would be so. My problem is that by biorthogonality, I can ascertain information about the relationships between terms in $(f_k)$ and terms in $(g_k)$, but minimality is a statement about the relations between terms of $(f_k)$. Can someone explain how this step is supposed to work?

Is there supposed to be an added condition about biorthogonal *complete* sequences, or rather $(g_k)$ being complete in $\overline{\operatorname{span}} \{ f_k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$? I ask because though I'm unfamiliar with the matter, it seems intuitively that it'd be easier to construct a biorthogonal sequence if you had more "ambient space" to work in, so perhaps I couldn't find a biorthogonal sequence composed of elements of $H$, but could if I widened my selection to some larger superspace $K$ in which $H$ (and thereby $(f_k)$) was imbedded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $j$ and consider the map $\phi(u)=\langle u,g_j\rangle$. Then $\phi$
is continuous, $\phi(f_j)=1$ and $\phi(f_k)=0$ for all $k\ne j$.
Therefore $\phi$ vanishes on $\text{span}_{k\ne j}\,f_k$ and so by
continuity, on its closure: so $f_j$ isn't in this closure.

Comment: I like this, but it seems "slick" in a way that seems to me like it might not be the "right" way to do, or perhaps not what the author had in mind when hand-waving the proof of that point. In your opinion, is there another way to show the point that might be more in line with what the author intended?

Comment: What about the other direction? Is there a similar argument?